# PHPUnit: Notification for untested methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, phpunit

Does PHPUnit have functionality (or an external manner) to reflect on the target object, and either fail or markTestIncomplete()'ish on methods which it does not have a test for?

To be clear; this would be in a situation where a test suite exists. A developer adds a new method, but neglects to write a test for it. Currently, it does not affect the unit testing process what-so-ever. I am looking for a way to change this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could enable code completion reporting, and look for red bits. Doesn't help if you're looking to automate something, but it's a nice visual cue at least.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have not messed with that. How does one go about enabling it?

Comment: See http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

Comment: Er sorry, brain fart, code coverage not code completion.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks, this is quite interesting. I'm going to use this. Unfortunately, as you pointed out, this really doesn't work for any kind of automation. I cannot hold a deployment based on this. Thanks however, I learned about something new. I appreciate it.

Comment: Check in hooks, and if you follow naming conventions for a test to method/function, then you could check with grep or other tool for the test to exist, and as such, fail the test in phpunit, similar to php_codesniffer checks.

Comment: PHPUnit can output a code coverage report. This includes details of every line of code in the system, and whether or not it's been executed as part of a test. There are many tools which allow you to analyse this data and get coverage percentages for every module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit can log code coverage data into a file with serialized data, which you can analyze later. This way you can find about untested methods:

```
 $ phpunit --coverage-php coveragedata.ser .
```

PHPUnit 3.7 itself has no way to fail when classes/methods are untested or when code coverage is below a treshold.